# Spacy not showing accurate vocab results

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, python-venv

I am trying to get similar words to an origin word using spacy. I've imported the `en_core_web_md` and `en_core_web_lg` models and I am using the word vectors to find words that are similar.

When I run this outside of my virtual environment, there is no issue; however, inside `venv`, when I run:

```py
dog = nlp.vocab[u'dog']
for x in dog.vocab:
    print(x.text)
```

it produces results such as:

```
Nothin
5
Nuthin’
ll
:)
'y
this
-_-
(ಠ_ಠ)
’em
```

which are not even remotely similar to 'dog.' When I try with other words such as 'lively' or 'banana', it gives exactly the same results as dog.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have two different versions of spacy, probably v2.2 in one venv and v2.3 in the other.

Instead of iterating over `nlp.vocab`, iterate over `nlp.vocab.vectors` instead, which should work in any version spacy v2 and avoid lexemes that don't have vectors:

```py
for orth in nlp.vocab.vectors:
    w = nlp.vocab[orth]
    # do something
```

See the section on preloaded vocab in the v2.3 migration guide here: https://spacy.io/usage/v2-3#migrating